# December 2013: Graph API search now returning less/different results than use facing search

Tags: facebook-graph-api, search

I have a small app for my private use that performs Graph API search on public posts - it basically has some extra filtering in it and pagination/time span options that makes it more useful than the user facing search. It has been working fine for about 6 months, but on or about mid-December 2013 or so, Graph API search started returning far less and different posts than the user facing search. It is easy to test this, in the Facebook developer's explorer tool, you can type a query like: "search?q=cat stuck tree&type=post" and then do the same search in facebook with "cat stuck tree" on public posts and see the differences. Previous to mid-December 2013, these searches returned the same results. Does anybody know what has changed?  (I made no changes to my code).

Answer (score 0):

It's because Facebook decided to just YANK away the possibility to search public posts. YET AGAIN. Sorry, but facebook totally sucks these days. They really do not care about the people using their platform. It goes from bad to worse.